# Do register globals effect undefined constant errors?

Tags: php, mysql

I was installing a travian script on localhost xammp, and i got a lot of errors.

four of them are notices that are supposed to have held the mysql information. "Use of undefined constant SQL_USE"

did those four errors happen because global registers were off? or does have nothing to do with this?

okay so there is a filed inside GameEngine that  config.php.
this file, the current file that is being executed, calls to config.php and config.php contains the following.

```
// ***** Database Username
define("SQL_USER", "root");

// ***** Database Password
define("SQL_PASS", "sergfree");

// ***** Database Name
define("SQL_DB", "trav");

// ***** Database - Table Prefix
define("TB_PREFIX", "s1_");
```

this is the include

```
include ("../../GameEngine/config.php");
```

this is the current file location C:\xampp\htdocs\install\include\multihunter.php
so why doesn't this work?

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_TYPE - assumed 'DB_TYPE' in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameEngine\Database.php on line 13

Notice: Use of undefined constant SQL_SERVER - assumed 'SQL_SERVER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameEngine\Database\db_MYSQL.php on line 17

Notice: Use of undefined constant SQL_USER - assumed 'SQL_USER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameEngine\Database\db_MYSQL.php on line 17

Notice: Use of undefined constant SQL_PASS - assumed 'SQL_PASS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameEngine\Database\db_MYSQL.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameEngine\Database\db_MYSQL.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (trying to connect via tcp://SQL_SERVER:3306) in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameEngine\Database\db_MYSQL.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameEngine\Database\db_MYSQL.php on line 17
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Comment: The register globals directive has nothing to do with this.

Comment: how do i find the missing config file? this is 2400 line long file, what can the code around that area possibly be? to make it easier to find the file.

Comment: Start by grepping for "define" and "SQL_SERVER"

Comment: i updated the question again. sorry it didn't work, i thought it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you forgot to include a config file where the SQL_ defines are done.

Based on your edit, UNCOMMENT those define lines:

```
// * Database Username 
define("SQL_USER", "root");
```

Comment: gratz on the 9k, and well, this is a script package, your supposed to install it. Guess they forgot to add it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are missing some required configuration. Register globals concerns only variables coming from the actual request (GET & POST parameters, cookies, environment). The missing constants in your case seem to be the actual database credentials, and apparently their absence results in an unsuccessful connection. Probably there should be some documentation describing how to set up the code, which you should read.

Comment: there is a read me file that says not to modify any comments lol

Answer (score 1):

The Notices are likely caused by you or the script author omitting quotation marks in array keys, e.g.:

```
$foo = $config[SQL_SERVER];
```

...where it should be:

```
$foo = $config['SQL_SERVER'];
```

With the former, PHP looks (correctly) for a constant named `SQL_SERVER` whose value to use for the array key, and when it doesn't find one decides you probably meant to use the string `'SQL_SERVER'`. This is one of PHP's worst "features" and that you're seeing these errors suggests that the author of the code is probably a novice.

It's also possible that the author has distributed a configuration file with lines like:

```
$foo = SQL_SERVER;
```

...with the assumption that you'll see this and replace it with e.g.

```
$foo = "10.0.0.2";
```

(This approach to configuration is also a bad practice since it causes—or should cause, anyway—runtime errors, instead of providing useful information, in the event the user has missed some configuration line.)

The package's `README` or equivalent should tell you where configuration values should be set—often this is a file named something like `config.php` or `config.inc.php`, or sometimes e.g. `config.sample.php` which you're intended to modify and then rename to `config.php`.